# XSLT 2.0 using the matches function with regular expression

Tags: templates, variables, xslt, match

I'm trying to write a very simple code but I'm not sure if It's possible in XSLT.

Suppose I have a variable called `name` (i.e. referenced as `$name`) and suppose I have an XML with bunch of names(`$NFD`).

I want to count the number of matches of this $name but not as-is but with a regular expression matching, that is:

`count($NFD//name-tag[matches(@filter,'^$name\||\|$name?', 'i')]) = 0)`.

***EXPLANATION:***

I'm trying to find matches of the following types:

1. `^$name\|` --> starting with `$name` variable and ends with pipe.
2. `\|$name?` --> starting with pipe and ends with my `$name` variable.

For some reason It seems like the integration of variable sign ($) in the regular expression inside the matches function fails to match correctly.

Is it possible? integrate regular expression including variable inside the matches function?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate strings in XSLT/XPath with the `concat` function so I think you simply want `count($NFD//name-tag[matches(@filter, concat('^', $name, '\||\|', $name,'?'), 'i')]) = 0)`. There is no variable interpolation happening inside string literals so you current expression would try to match on the string with a dollar symbol followed by the string `name`. But my `concat` suggestion should work.

Comment: Thank you very much Martin - It was very important to me.